# Compare .csv and add only rows with updated values

Tags: powershell

I have 2 .csv files, they have matching columns, I am trying to compare the two and have a final output .csv that only has the differences

`corpold.csv` is a previous imported file.
`corpnew.csv` is the new import file.

I need to export a CSV that includes all items that are not in `corpold.csv`, only changed items that exist in both CSVs and exclude any rows that exist in `corpold.csv` but not in `corpnew.csv`.

```
$reference = Import-Csv -Path D:\corpold.csv
$lookup = $reference | Group-Object -AsHashTable -AsString -Property EMPID

$results = Import-Csv -Path D:\corpnew.csv | foreach {
    $email = $_.EMAIL_ADDRESS
    $status = $_.ACTIVE
    $fs = $_.FIRST_NAME
    $ls = $_.LAST_NAME
    $id = $_.EMPID
    $title = $_.JOB_TITLE
    $code = $_.JOB_CODE
    $type = $_.USER_TYPE
    $designee = $_.DESIGNEE
    $stores = $_.STORES
    $hiredate = $_.HIRE_DATE
    $dept = $_.DEPARTMENT
    $grp = $_.GROUP

    if ($lookup.ContainsKey($id)) {
        # if exists in yesterdays file

        # trying to figure out how to compare and only provide results into
        # the Export-Csv that have changed while excluding any items in
        # corpold that do not exist in corpnew
    } else {
        # if it does not exist update all fields
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            ACTIVE = $status
            EMAIL_ADDRESS = $email
            FIRST_NAME = $fs
            LAST_NAME = $ls
            EMPID = $id
            JOB_TITLE = $title
            JOB_CODE = $code
            USER_TYPE = $type
            DESIGNEE = $designee
            STORES = $stores
            HIRE_DATE = $hiredate
            DEPARTMENT = $dept
            GROUP = $grp
        }
    }
}

# Sample outputs
$results
$results | Export-Csv -Path D:\delta.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two operations to be done here: find differences and compare objects which exist in both files.

### Compare objects and find new/deleted entries

To compare object you can utilize [`Compare-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object?view=powershell-6) cmdlet like this:

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $reference -DifferenceObject $results -Property EMPID -IncludeEqual
```

This will give you the list of `EMPID` and `SideIndicator` showing whether object exist only in first (`<=`), only in second (`=>`) or in both (`==`). You can filter by `SideIndicator`and then process it accordingly.

Alternative way is to use [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-6) like this:

```
$reference | Where-Object empid -NotIn $results.empid
$reference | Where-Object empid -In    $results.empid
$results   | Where-Object empid -NotIn $reference.empid
```

First one will give you entries only in first file, second one results existing in both, last one will give you entries only existing in second file.

### Find edited entries

What you basically have to do is to iterate all the entries and then check if any of the columns has been changed. If yes, add it to `$changedEntries`.

Example of script:

```
$IDsInBoth = $results | Where-Object empid -In $reference.empid | Select-Object -ExpandProperty EMPID
$AllProperties = $results | Get-Member | Where-Object MemberType -eq "NoteProperty" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
$changedEntries = @()
$IDsInBoth | ForEach-Object {
  $changed = $false
  $newEntry = $results   | Where-Object EMPID -eq $_
  $oldEntry = $reference | Where-Object EMPID -eq $_
  foreach ($p in $AllProperties) {
    if ($oldEntry."$p" -ne $newEntry."$p") {
    $changed = $true
    }
  }
  if ($changed) {
    $changedEntries += $newEntry
  }
}
```